# 'Package zendframework/zend-diactoros is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-diactoros instead.'

Tags: laravel, zend-framework, laminas, laminas-api-tools, mezzio

I have only upgraded to Laravel ^6.0 from 5.8*.
On running $ `composer require laravel/passport` 
I have got error message "Package zendframework/zend-diactoros is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-diactoros instead."

I have installed [laminas-json](https://packagist.org/packages/laminas/laminas-json)

Will that suffice?

Answer (score 7):

https://www.zend.com/blog/what-status-zend-framework-transition-laminas

everything zend framework is being transitioned to laminas open source project. There's a lot of projects going to be popping up these messages as zend.

Answer (score 0):

The update to use `laminas/laminas-diactoros` was made in v8.2.0. Using a more recent version of `laravel/passport` will solve the questioned issue.